# Resizing image size using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize the image using javascript, but I am getting errors

```
 var y;
            var y = new Image();
            y.src = s;
            var wd = y.width/600;
            var ht =  y.height/600;


    if(ht>wd){
        var rw=round(wd * (1/ht));
        var hw1 = ht * (1/ht);
        var hw=round(hw1);
    } else {
        var rw1 = (wd) * (1/wd); 
        rw=round(rw1);
        hw=round(ht * (1/wd));
    }
```

I am getting errors saying

Message: Object expected
Line: 27
Char: 2
Code: 0

Where line 27 is `rw=round(rw1);`

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Are your images always larger than 600x600 pixels?

Comment: Yes,
Would the above code not be appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `round` method is not a global function, it's a method in the `Math` object.

Change every `round` in your code to `Math.round`.